# Is there a way to perform a transaction that writes to auth, firestore and storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to firebase and I want to add it to my vuejs project.
But I'm wondering. Is the a way I can perform a transaction that creates user using the auth() and use the uid to create a user using firestore() and use the uid as a name to upload an image using storage(). However, the whole operation should revert, should any fail.

Answer (score 2):

There are no cross-product transactions available for Firebase products.  Of the three products you mentioned, only Firestore has transactions, and they are limited to documents within a single database.

What you will have to do is check for errors each step of the way, and undo any previous changes if something fails.

Comment: Any new updates?