# How to make a user deletion transaction in Firebase Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How can I make a Firebase Auth user deletion belong to a transaction with update of a Firestore document?

My code (without transaction) is as follows:

```dart
  /// Deletes user account
  static Future<void> deleteUserAccount(shokaze.User user) async {
    try {
      await _auth.currentUser!.delete();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error while deleting user: $e");

      if (e.code == "requires-recent-login") {
        await _reauthenticateAndDelete();
      } else {
        // Handle other Firebase exceptions
      }

      user.storeMarkAsDeleted();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error while deleting user: $e");

      // Handle general exception
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Where `storeMarkAsDeleted()` is simply:

```dart
  /// Marks user as deleted
  Future<void> storeMarkAsDeleted() async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .doc(id)
        .update({
      "deleted": true,
    });
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?  Please provide your debugging details with a description of what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: How can I make the auth deletion belongs to a transaction with update of the collection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to execute a transaction atomically across different Google Cloud products (in your case, Firebase Auth and Firesore).  They are completely different systems, unified only by how you choose to use them together in your app (and how security rules use Auth to determine who can read and write a Firestore document).

Similar questions have been asked before:

- [Is there a way to perform a transaction that writes to auth, firestore and storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529639/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-transaction-that-writes-to-auth-firestore-and-stora)
- [Couple Firebase Firestore and Firebase Storage calls together into a batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740838/couple-firebase-firestore-and-firebase-storage-calls-together-into-a-batch)